# How to use Router link active for all children

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, single-page-application

I have side nav with nested routes.my in click on the first button inside navbar it goto the `doctors/doctors-list` and router link active work perfectly. but I have other children routers like `doctors/creat`, `doctors/update:id` when I am going to those routes my router link is not activated as expected. my app structure is when the user first clicks on the doctor button it `doctors/doctors-list`
when user select doctor from the list route will be changed to the 'doctors/update:id'.how to slove this issue

```
<a  routerLink="doctors/doctors-list" routerLinkActive="active"></a>
```

my routes config

```
{
        path: 'doctors',
        component: DoctorsHomeComponent,
        children: [
        {
            path: 'doctors-list',
            component: DoctorsComponent,
        },
        {
            path: 'doctors/creat',
            component: DoctorsPageComponent,
        },
        {
            path: 'update-doctor/:id',
            component: DoctorsPageComponent,
        }

        ]

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you try this

```
@Component

import { Router } from '@angular/router';``

constructor(public router: Router) {}

isdoctorsActive(exact) {
    return this.router.isActive('doctors/', exact);
}

@html
<a  routerLink="doctors/doctors-list" [ngClass]="{'active': isdoctorsActive(false)}"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the following tag in your doctor components html page

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Comment: yeah. since I'm using the router-outlet I have to tell which component needs to render when the user clicks on the parent components

Answer (score 0):

You need to use lazy routing here -

In your app-routing.module.ts you can load doctor module like below code

```
const routes: Routes = [
 {
  path: '',
  component: LandingComponent,
 },
 {
  path: 'doctors',
  loadChildren: 'doctor.module#DoctorModule'
 }    
];
```

Once it loads doctor module then it loads the component which it founds in the URL

Below code will be in your doctor-routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [ 
  { path: 'doctors-list', component: DoctorsComponent},
  { path: 'create', component: DoctorsPageComponent},
  { path: 'create/:id', component: DoctorsPageComponent}      
];
```

Above routes you can use like this -

1. It loads doctors component

   `<a routerLink="doctors/doctors-list" routerLinkActive="active"></a>`
2. It loads doctors page component in create mode

   `<a routerLink="doctors/create" routerLinkActive="active"></a>`
3. It loads doctors page component in edit mode

   `<a routerLink="['doctors/create', id]" routerLinkActive="active"></a>`